# VBA Cut and Paste error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to cut the contents of cell **K7** (100) and paste it into **M7** using VBA (see below) but I keep getting an error (see below). Where am I going wrong?:

```
Sub CutPaste()    
    Worksheets("Sheet2Test").Activate
    Range("K7").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("M7").Select
    Selection.Paste   
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: And which line are you getting the error on?

Comment: +1 Thanks for your reply. When I debug, I'm getting the error on the 6th line ( Selection.Paste)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Its better to avoid `Select` altogether.  Use this

```
Worksheets("Sheet2Test").Range("K7").Cut Worksheets("Sheet2Test").Range("M7")
```

Comment: It works great but I'm trying to understand how this line paste the data.

Answer (score 6):

Just replace `Selection.Paste` for `ActiveSheet.Paste` , so it would be:

```
Sub CutPaste()    
    Worksheets("Sheet2Test").Activate
    Range("K7").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("M7").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

That would do the paste as you wanted.